# Using/Binding 'this' with Bookshelf Promises in ES6

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-promise, hapi.js, bookshelf.js

I'm having issues getting ES6 Arrow functions working properly with my Bookshelf/Bluebird promise chain.

This is the working code when using ES5 and Bluebird's `.bind({})`:

```
exports.prospectorLead = function (query) {
    return new Lead().where('id', query.lead_id).fetch({withRelated: Lead.RELATED, require: true })
    .bind({})
    .then(function (lead) {

        this.lead = lead.serialize();
        this.company = this.lead.company.serialize();

        return API('prospector', 'v1/people/search', {
          query: query.domain,
        });
    })
    .then(function (prospects) {
       console.log(this.lead.id, this.company.domain, prospects);
    })
}
```

This is the broken code when using ES6 Arrow functions that do not have `this` set properly:

```
exports.prospectorLead = function (query) {
  return new Lead().where('id', query.lead_id).fetch({withRelated: Lead.RELATED, require: true })
  .then((lead) => {

    this.lead = lead.serialize();
    this.company = this.lead.company.serialize();

    return API('prospector', 'v1/people/search', {
      query: query.domain
    });
  })
  .then((prospects) => {
    console.log(this.lead.id, this.company.domain, prospects);
  })
}
```

The problem I'm seeing is that the scope of `this` is set not to the `exports.propspectorLead()` function, but instead to the scope of the whole module. Which was not an issue when calling the function one off, but when I make a ton of async calls to this function, my data becomes corrupt because `this` is not scoped properly.

What am I missing here? I was under the assumption that using the arrow functions would allow me to use `this` throughout my promise chain.

Comment: Notice that for the actual problem which you're trying to solve with `bind` there are [much better solutions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28250680/1048572).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; that's exactly the opposite of what arrow functions do.

Arrow functions use strictly *lexical* `this` – they inherit the `this` of their containing block.

No matter what you `bind()` or manually pass as `this` when calling the arrow function, its `this` will always come from the containing scope.